# Huawei C8812: No Debuggable Applications

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat, android-logcat

My Huawei C8812 phone doesn't show anything while debugging, But when I use other phones, it shows. How to solve this problem.

[image: sample]

Comment: Have you enabled developer options?

Comment: Any chance you didn't turn on USB debugging in developer settings? Or that the adb connection is working? $ adb devies ?

Comment: I turn on USB debugging. I do everything. It doesn't change in Huawei C8812. but others are ok.

Comment: you have to download the drivers for the device, enable Developer Options, Enable USB Debugging

Answer (score 0):

OK, since I had another Huawei P8 I ran into the same problem. This time I have the exact answer.

Follow these instructions (from denispyr's answer on Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?)

Dial

```
*#*#2846579#*#*
```

and you will see a hidden menu. Go to `Project Menu / Background Setting / Log setting` and define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting).

And then make sure you restart your phone.

Please note this probably only applies to Huawei phones.

Comment: What should I do in _LogSetting_ step? Log switch (on ?) and Log level setting ??

Comment: Three first options should be checked